# To detect null cells in a column which includes list and Nan

Tags: python, list, nan

I have a dataframe, which has a column includes list and Nan. I want to replace all the empty list and Nan with {}.

My data is:

```
df['c'] = [[l1],[l2]], [], Nan
```

I have tried using -

```
df['c'].apply(lambda x: {} if pd.isna(x) or len(x)==0 else x[0])
```

It would return

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

because for `[[l1], [l2]]`, it would return `[false, false]`

I tried using the code below for NaN -

```
df['c'].apply(lambda x: {} if pd.isna(x).all() or len(x)==0 else x[0])
```

This returns

```
'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: Why don't you use method fillna:
df['c'].fillna(value='{}'), but your dataframe looks strange. It's only series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample dataframe using

```
df['c'] = [[4,5],[1,2,3]], [], np.nan

# Output
    c
0   [[4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]
1   []
2   NaN
```

This should work -

```
df['c'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: {} if x == [] or x is np.nan else x)
```

Comment: You might want to mark that as an accepted answer so that the people with the same problem know what's working!